# Unusual, uninformative error with dplyr summarize_all: "Error: not expecting this"?

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

Using a script I developed a few months ago and that I use often, as of late (~within the past week) I have been facing an issue with a peculiar error thrown by dplyr::summarize_all(). Has anyone encountered this before, and have some leads on potential fixes?

I've tried removing/re-installing tidyverse and dplyr, and just updated my R version.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Generate a dataframe
df <- tibble(
  year = c(rep(2000, 365), rep(2001, 365)),
  day = c(1:730),
  temperature = rnorm(730, mean = 10, sd = 3)
)

# summarize() works fine
df %>%
  group_by(year, day) %>%
  summarize(temp = mean(temperature))
```

```
# A tibble: 730 x 3
# Groups:   year [2]
    year   day  temp
   <dbl> <int> <dbl>
 1  2000     1  7.62
 2  2000     2  7.08
 3  2000     3 10.6 
 4  2000     4 11.4 
 5  2000     5 10.1 
 6  2000     6  7.18
 7  2000     7 13.2 
 8  2000     8  8.64
 9  2000     9  9.42
10  2000    10 10.1 
# … with 720 more rows
```

```
# summarize_all() and summarise_all() do not
df %>%
  group_by(year, day) %>%
  summarize_all(mean)
```

```
Error: not expecting this
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

```
df %>%
  group_by(year, day) %>%
  summarise_all(mean)
```

```
Error: not expecting this
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

```
# Relevant session info
sessionInfo()
```

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.5

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] forcats_0.4.0   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_0.8.1     purrr_0.3.2     readr_1.3.1     tidyr_0.8.3    
[7] tibble_2.1.3    ggplot2_3.1.1   tidyverse_1.2.1
```

Comment: Both of them work fine for me without any error. Can you try restarting your session, loading only `dplyr` and check again?

Comment: Did you try `summarise_all(funs(mean))` ?

Comment: From googling, it looks like that error was from a short-lived commit to dplyr from a version this week. I'd suggest restarting a fresh R session, reinstalling `dplyr`, and then restarting R again.

Comment: I raised an [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4412) on the same and the fix was to update `dplyr` by using the developer version.

Comment: Thanks all. @NelsonGon if you mark your comment as an answer I can accept, this worked for me (more specifically the dev version of dplyr provided a more informative error, which pointed to a solution: I had a value "mean" in my workspace that was confusing summarize_all)